# how to make a custom dot in regexp?

Tags: python, regex

The normal dot match all of characters except line break. If I want to match all of characters include line break, I can use [\s\S](just an example) to get the right result.

But how about some cases like " match all of the characters except ';' "?

or " match all of the characters except 'A' and 'b' and 'c' "?

how can I custom a dot with a * to match what I want?

Comment: Regex flavor vary dramatically. Some (.NET, Python's regex) support sets. Which regex? Awk, old Python, sed, Javascript not even close to being able to do this...

Comment: @dawg: He's tagged this Python, so he presumably doesn't care about POSIX regex, JavaScript, etc. Also, which old Python didn't support sets of characters as a character class? I'm pretty sure Python's regex engine borrowed its syntax from perl right from the start. As has JavaScripts. Not to mention that even POSIX basic regexes support it. I can't think of any flavor that _doesn't_.

Comment: @abarnert: I meant the form of `/[[a-z]--[aeiou]]/` as an example which POSIX, sed, Python re, definitely do not support as a shorthand for all non-vowel letters.

Comment: @dawg: Sure, but he didn't ask for that, he asked for all characters except `;`, or all characters except `A`, `B`, and `C`, and all of them support `[^;]` and `[^ABC]`. And meanwhile, you said that "Python" supports sets but "old Python" doesn't; Python 3.5 and 1.5 both support `[^;]` and neither supports `[a-z]--[aeiou]`; nothing relevant has changed.

Comment: @abarnert: I think we are misunderstanding each other. ;-)  I agree with you. When I said 'old Python' I meant re vs regex. Sure, he can do `[^Abc]` and that will match all characters other than `Abc` include a line break. Guess I was trying to introduce set operations when he said `how can I custom a dot with a * to match what I want?` A truly custom dot is probably more than simple inclusion or negation from a range. regex can do more complete set operations I guess is my point...

Comment: @dawg: Yeah, I think it's just that you're assuming that `regex` is already "part of Python", while I'm forgetting that it's ever going to be there after being bumped from the release schedule 3 times in a row. :) (Either that, or you've actually got a time machine and can tell me when Matthew will finally be happy with it and check it in. Or maybe something more profitable, like who wins the next World Series.:)

Comment: There was a time before `re` which honestly I thought you meant with "old Python".

Answer (score 1):

To get dot to match a linebreak as well, use `re.DOTALL` as an option. For example:

```
In [4]: print re.match("A.+B","A\n\nB")
None

In [5]: print re.match("A.+B","A\n\nB",re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10c5d17e8>
```

This changes *all* dots in your expression, though. Alternatively, you could use (|) to only match "\n" in some cases:

```
In [6]: print re.match("A(?:\n|.)+B","A\n\nB")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ca5feb8>
```

Here we use ?: in order to keep from making a group. Each `(?:\n|.)` will match a dot *or* a newline.

For the other things, you generally use "[]" or "[^]" to match only a set of things, or anything but a set of things. So for anything but ';', use "[^;]", and for all characters except A, b, and c, use "[^Abc]", while to *only* match those three, use "[Abc]". There are also all sorts of shorthand things, like \s for whitespace, and \S for non-whitespace. Looking through [the `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) is really helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

The Python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module and some other regex flavor support sets operations in character classes beyond simple negation.

For example, in Python regex (but not in re in the standard library):

```
>>> import regex
>>> s='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> regex.findall(r'(?V1)[[a-z]--[c-o]]', s)
['a', 'b', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

The character class `[a-z]` would usually find all ascii lower case letters. In this case, not including any between `[c-o]` because they were subtracted.

The sense of that can be negated as well:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'(?V1)[^[a-z]--[c-o]]', s)
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

Or, no vowels:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'(?V1)[[a-zA-Z]--[aAeEiIoOuU]]', s)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: The `re` module in the standard library _also_ supports sets. It doesn't support set operations like difference, but then he doesn't need such operations for any of the examples he asked for.